# How does various cols differ in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very basic question on `bootstrap` grid system. I have read the docs and tutorials, but this part does not get into my head.

**col-sm-6**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**col-lg-6**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. `sm` targets for medium sized and tables
2. `lg` targets for larger desktops.

Both the grids work perfectly, Both are `responsive` and both `works` perfectly. Can anyone explain me the difference in both the approaches.

1. I want to understand what does these two in `common` and where do they
   `differ`?
2. Why would one want to build the grid layout in `first` approach and
   why would one choose the `second` one?.

Comment: They are in common because they will be six lengths apart on their relative screen size. They differ because they are for specific screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, they are the same thing. The classes differ by each screen size. In a small screen size, you may see something different then in a big screen size depending on the amount of columns you want. In better terms, you can combine the classes to keep a responsive layout responsive. I will attach a demo below for you to look at. But first let's take a look at the following layout:

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6 blue2">
    </div>
     <div class=" col-lg-6 red2">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue2 {
    background:blue;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.red2 {
    background:red;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The following will produce a specific layout for the large screens but will not follow the grid system for screens that are smaller. This is best seen through the next example:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 blue"></div>
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6  red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue {
    background:blue;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.red {
    background:red;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```

This is the exact same CSS but I have added more classes to cover the different screen sizes. The classes are: `col-md-6` and `col-sm-6`. Together, along with the original class demonstrated above: `col-lg-6`, they will maintain the exact layout through every screen size (I have even included extra small in this design).

This is best seen through the following [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nBwwv/1/). Just play with the screen size on the bottom right and it will make more sense.

Comment: You mean to say that if i have a row with two cols[col-sm-6], this would work only in tablets and medium sized browsers but will fail in extra small and larger desktops?

Comment: You are correct. The first example demonstrates this with the use of only col-lg-6.

Comment: Actually, it won't "fail." If you specify ONLY col-sm-6 then it will collapse to 100% the width of it's containing element for the xs sizes and it will be 6-columns wide at the md and lg breakpoints.  Think of col values as additive, meaning col-sm applies to ≥768px.  Every size (xs, sm, md, lg) value you provide is like saying: "I want the grid to look like this above this size UNTIL I give you different instructions for a larger size."

Answer (score 2):

The grid system is meant to target different device screen using [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

As an example is much more clear, lets analyse this one:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first thing to know is that Bootstrap has a grid of **12 columns**.
When you add a class `col-lg-x`, x can be a number between **1** and **12** which tell how many columns you want your element to fill.

- On a large screen `col-lg-x`, where the width is **≥ 1200px** (e.g. desktops), the four divs will be on the same line.
- On small screens `col-sm-x`, where the width is **≥ 750px** (e.g. tablets), you will have two lines containing two div each
- On extra small screens `col-xs-x`, where the width is **lower than 750px** (e.g. phones), each div will be on a separate line.

There is also a `col-md-x` class to target devices where width is **≥ 750px**, but since its not on this example the `col-sm-6` will apply instead.

You can read more about *Bootstrap Media queries* on the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

**Edit:**
The media queries actually target the size of the window. So when you want to see how your page will appear on a smaller/larger device you just need to *resize* your browser.